# How to get the permanent URL of a given mail when using Gmail Preview Pane

Tags: gmail

The standard Gmail interface provides you with a permanent URL for the mail you are currently reading.

Unfortunately, when the "Preview Pane" Lab application is activated, 
no specific reusable URL is available in browser's URL text box.

How to get a permanent URL for a mail without disabling the "Preview Pane" Lab application?